# Return a copy of a UIImage instead of change in place

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm a newbie at iOS development, and have run into something that seems odd to me. I've got the following method to take a large image and make a smaller version of it, then upload both to a server:

```
- (void)prepareAndUploadImages
{
  UIImage *originalImage = self.imageView.image;
  UIImage *smallerImage = [originalImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:CGSizeMake(1024.0, 768.0) interpolationQuality:1];
  [self uploadImage:originalImage withFilename:@"original.jpg"];
  [self uploadImage:smallerImage withFilename:@"smaller.jpg"];
}
```

This is uploading the images fine, but the weird thing is when they land on the server the `"original.jpg"` image is actually the shrunk version and `"smaller.jpg"` is the full-size image.

I'm using the `UIImage resizedImageWithContentMode:` method from [UIImageCategories](https://github.com/ezrover/UIImage-Categories), it's return looks like this:

```
return [self resizedImage:newSize interpolationQuality:quality];
```

The resizedImage:interpolationQuality method it's calling returns this:

```
return [self resizedImage:newSize transform:transform drawTransposed:drawTransposed interpolationQuality:quality];
```

That resizedImage:transform:... method call returns like this:

```
// Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef scale:self.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

...

return newImage;
```

So, I would really have expected my code to be setting `smallerImage` to this new image that is created as a return value from the method called on the original image, but instead it appears the behavior is that the original image is modified in place, but before it is modified in place it returns self? I don't know, it seems really weird.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here, and how I can fix my code to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: I suggest adding log statements and seeing what you really have with the two images - the description probably has a lot by you can look at -scale and -size too. Does this open source software deal with retina (2x) images properly?

Comment: So if you only upload `originalImage` everything works as expected? Also, you could just upload only the original image to server and perform any operations there to save bandwidth.

Comment: If I just upload `originalImage` without calling any methods on it, it goes through as its original size. If I use the same method but just comment out the upload for `originalImage`, the `smallerImage` is still the full size image. Calling the method on original image seems to be editing it in place, what I don't understand is what that method call is returning.

Comment: change the UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Comment: Could you provide the size and width of each image just before the uploadImade method is called please

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

I thought the original image was actually larger than 1024 across, but it wasn't. Then what was happening, is the size is given in POINTS, not PIXELS, so the "smaller" image I was making is actually upscaling the image, not downscaling the image. That's what was throwing me off.

If I cut the size in half I get the pixel dimensions I'm looking for.

Thanks for the comments, they helped!